# multiline text in semantic mediawiki subobjects

Tags: mediawiki, multiline, semantic-mediawiki, subobject

Is it possible to assign a multiline text value in a semantic mediawiki subobject ?
I'd like to do something like

```
{{#subobject:
|multiline=line1
a list on line 2:
*list item 1 on line3
*list item 2 on line4
|foo=bar
}}
```

setting multiline texts for ordinary objects works with

```
[[multiline1::<br>
list
*item 1
*item 2]]
```

I wonder if it's possible for subobjects as I would like to attach multiline notes for to do subobjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is:

```
{{#subobject:
|multiline=line1
a list on line 2:
*list item 1 on line3
*list item 2 on line4
|foo=bar
}}
```

This will give an error message that the multi line content "line1..." can not be used as a page title.
This is because the default property type is page. You need to change the property type via special page [[Property:multiline]]
See http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:List_of_datatypes  e.g. http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Property:SomeProperty has the type text, which is declared via

```
[[Has type::Text]]
```

So you might want to do the same for your multiline property.
The following query shows the wanted result:

```
{{#ask:
[[foo::+]]
|?multiline
|?foo
}}
```